# MySQL JSON_OBJECT returning unparsable JSON

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users similar to the statement below, (relevant fields included)

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  IsActive BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

When I query the table with a simple `SELECT` statements, I get the fields back exactly as expected.

```
+----------------------------+
| ID | Username   | IsActive |
+----+------------+----------+
| 42 | CoolGuy92  |        1 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

That's all well and good. If, though, I try to run the following query, and send its output to the browser for use, I get this error on the client side when trying to parse the return: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position X`.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    "ID", Users.ID,
    "Username", Users.Username,
    "IsActive", Users.IsActive
)
FROM Users
```

**What is causing this parsing error?**

Answer (score 0):

The parsing error occurs due to your `IsActive` column being the `BIT` data type. `BIT` columns have a charset and collation of `binary`, and are thusly stored as binary. An apparent value of `1` is actually stored as `0x01`. During a normal query, MySQL will output the value of a `BIT` column using the schema's default character set, often treating it as an integer[*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html#:%7E:text=To%20ensure%20numeric%20treatment%20of%20a%20bit%20literal,%20use%20it%20in%20numeric%20context.). So for most cases, an apparent value of `1`, becomes `0x31` and `0` becomes `0x30`. This allows the returned values to be readable, and easily used as numbers or strings.

In the case of `JSON_OBJECT` though,

> Strings produced by converting JSON values have a character set of `utf8mb4` and a collation of `utf8mb4_bin`[*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#:%7E:text=Strings%20produced%20by%20converting%20JSON%20values%20have%20a%20character%20set%20of%20utf8mb4%20and%20a%20collation%20of%20utf8mb4_bin)

By making this conversion, the field's literal value is used and is output as `\u0001`. This is not escaped in any way, so when your browser attempts to parse the output, it fails when it reaches such a value.

To get around this, you can cast your `BIT` columns to another numeric datatype in your `JSON_OBJECT` call, or add 0 to it[*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html#:%7E:text=To%20ensure%20numeric%20treatment%20of%20a%20bit%20literal,%20use%20it%20in%20numeric%20context.).

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    "ID", Users.ID,
    "Username", Users.Username,
    "IsActive", Users.IsActive + 0
)
FROM Users
```